# "No view found for id" when working with RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I am trying my first steps with RecyclerViews. I got very far and I understand everything. However I get an "No view found for id ..." error when trying to run the code.

This is the onCreateView Method of DictionaryFragment:

```
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dictionary_list, container, false);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.dictionaryList);
    adapter = new DictionaryAdapter(getActivity(), getDictionaryData());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    return rootView;
    }
```

The dictionary_list.xml looks like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@color/grey"
android:paddingBottom="8dp"
android:paddingLeft="8dp"
android:paddingRight="8dp">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/dictionaryList"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</LinearLayout>
```

And this is the error message:

```
04-16 16:15:15.119: E/AndroidRuntime(15843): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-16 16:15:15.119: E/AndroidRuntime(15843): Process: com.tonestar.dict, PID: 15843
04-16 16:15:15.119: E/AndroidRuntime(15843): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.tonestar.dict/com.tonestar.dict.view.dictionary.DictionaryActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0a003f (com.tonestar.dict:id/container) for fragment DictionaryFragment{3b7c893c #0 id=0x7f0a003f}
04-16 16:15:15.119: E/AndroidRuntime(15843):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
04-16 16:15:15.119: E/AndroidRuntime(15843):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
04-16 16:15:15.119: E/AndroidRuntime(15843):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
04-16 16:15:15.119: E/AndroidRuntime(15843):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
04-16 16:15:15.119: E/AndroidRuntime(15843):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-16 16:15:15.119: E/AndroidRuntime(15843):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
04-16 16:15:15.119: E/AndroidRuntime(15843):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
04-16 16:15:15.119: E/AndroidRuntime(15843):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
04-16 16:15:15.119: E/AndroidRuntime(15843):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
04-16 16:15:15.119: E/AndroidRuntime(15843):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
04-16 16:15:15.119: E/AndroidRuntime(15843):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
04-16 16:15:15.119: E/AndroidRuntime(15843): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0a003f (com.tonestar.dict:id/container) for fragment DictionaryFragment{3b7c893c #0 id=0x7f0a003f}
04-16 16:15:15.119: E/AndroidRuntime(15843):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:886)
04-16 16:15:15.119: E/AndroidRuntime(15843):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
04-16 16:15:15.119: E/AndroidRuntime(15843):    at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:834)
04-16 16:15:15.119: E/AndroidRuntime(15843):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1452)
04-16 16:15:15.119: E/AndroidRuntime(15843):    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6005)
04-16 16:15:15.119: E/AndroidRuntime(15843):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2288)
04-16 16:15:15.119: E/AndroidRuntime(15843):    ... 10 more
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup your RecyclerView in the onViewCreated method

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
     recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.dictionaryList);
     adapter = new DictionaryAdapter(getActivity(), getDictionaryData());
     recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
     recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
}
```

and inflate the view in onCreateView

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.dictionary_list, container, false);    
}
```

The reason for this behaviour being that inflater.inflate only doesn't actually inflate the view to avoid jamming the ui thread and is run asynchronous later. When the inflater is done onViewCreated is called. It is generally bad practice to do anything in the onCreateView buzt creating views or calling the inflater.

Comment: Thank you, @JarodCoding , but this didn't help.
Actually the example on the android developer page does it the same way I do with inflating the recycler view in onCreateView:
[link]https://developer.android.com/samples/RecyclerView/src/com.example.android.recyclerview/RecyclerViewFragment.html#l71